# How to add a gradient to a colored ImageView icon?

Tags: android

I'm showing an icon with a dynamically set color.

Question: how can I add a gradient to the icon? Eg that the color that I set is always the "end" color of the gradient, and the start color is always a but "lighter"?

Definition:

```
<ImageView android:id="@id+/someicon" android:src="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now" />
```

Color set:

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.someicon)
icon.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Android API 16.

Comment: Could you post what your icon looks like after running this code? Your explanation did feel clear enough

Comment: The example above shows the "speak now" default android icon in color plain red. I want to add a gradient to that icon, eg going from lightred to red; or from red to black. Whatever, I'd just like to know how to apply a gradient instead of a plain color to any icon.